# How to call $.ajax inside of Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

How can a jQuery Ajax call be made from within Node.js? app.js outputs the following error:

> $.ajax is not a function

**app.js**

```
var $ = require('jQuery');

$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.example.com/resource/example.json",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      "$limit" : 5000,
      "$$app_token" : "MY_TOKEN"
    }
}).done(function(data) {
  // Logic
});
```

Comment: Use this package for send request is better https://github.com/request/request

Comment: What am I missing here? Why would anyone use jQuery on Node? There are no issues with browser support and compability on Node.

Comment: The API I am calling provides sample code in jQuery. But I would like to call from a server instead of the browser in order to process the data.

Comment: I suggest to learn what HTTP request is, structure of it and how it works (in JS and Node), then you'd be able to translate Ajax to JS without any effort and pick up some knowledge, win-win.

Comment: @Solo I understand HTTP requests, just unfamiliar with Node.js.

Comment: In that case, [articles like this](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html) are beneficial.

Comment: There are potential valid reasons to use jQuery on Node, because jQuery offers more than just cross-browser fills and syntactic sugar. For example, jQuery templates. Disconnected DOM handling. Etc. Not in this case, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use request or axios or even the core http module in node not jQuery.

An example using request:

```
  var request = require('request');
      request({ url: 'http://api.example.com/resource/example.json’, qs: {
  "$limit" : 5000,
  "$$app_token" : "MY_TOKEN"
} }, function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
      // Print the response status code if a response was received
       console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTTP body
    });
```

Comment: The Request package has been recommended in comments above.. It would have been nice to see how the example above could be translated into a "Request" call.

Comment: @crayden he doesn’t do anything with the example, but code is now updated to use the same uri and querystring parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think jquery ajax is supported, but you can use something like ajax-request if you want jquery-like ajax syntax: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajax-request. Or just use request https://github.com/request/request

Answer (score 0):

You're not suppose to use jQuery inside node. They do different things, node is for back-end and jQuery for front end.

If you need to make an API call use [request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

And here the sample to use it:

```
var options = {
host: "the-end-point-host",
  port: 80, // the port
  path: '/the-path',
  method: 'POST' // HTTP verb you wnat to use
};

http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
}).end();
```